# if I delete a row in SQLite, how can I make other below rows to go up and fill the deleted row?

Tags: swift, sqlite

```
3|banana|sweet|tomato
4|happy|sad|love
```

I deleted the first and the second row, I'd like the others(the 3rd and the 4th) to go up and each of them to become the first and the second. How can I do this?

For example, the query for creating table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dfl (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, A TEXT, B TEXT, C TEXT)
```

The query for deleting row:

```sql
delete from dfl where ID=1
```

Comment: Leave the database engine alone to maintain the integrity of your data. You just need to focus on how to manipulate your data. Also, you don't need the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword since the `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` means the ID is auto incremented field. Please read [this](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: SQLite keeps in mind whether a primary key was already used before and will not use it again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Actually you don't do this!

Don't mess with the autoincrement keys. The DB needs it to identify the record. Leave it. If you need a rank column then you can generate it on-the-fly in your select query:

```
SELECT *, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY id) rank_column
FROM dfl 
order by id
```